# Black and white spots

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, 3d, render-settings

I'm very new to Photoshop I'm facing some problem in post-production.

I'm getting wired black spots while I'm working on the 32-bit channel. When I convert my 32bit to 16bit channel using a smart object I'm getting white spots in my image.

[image][image]

[image]

Comment: yes its rendered image its been rendered perfectly as i try to modify layers in photoshop its getting affected  with black spots and after converting to smart object u can see white noise

Comment: please have check on re-post on render image

Comment: So, what is the problem with the rendered image?  What are you trying to fix with all those filters? What are you trying to achieve?  If you can edit your question, mention what you are trying to achieve, there may be a better way to do it.

Comment: You have a few masks on those layers, have you tried deactivating the masks and checking the result? Do you still get the black spots?

Comment: @BillyKerr im trying make night scene as i turn on my gi layer and reflection and refraction layer this is what is happening to my scene

Comment: @Luciano yes i tried  problem with gi reflection and refraction layers lighting layer too if i turn off i dont seem to have any dots

Comment: OK, so instead of adding all those filters, try converting your rendered image to a Smart Object. Then use the Adobe Camera RAW filter to reduce the exposure, reduce the shadows and highlights, to make everything darker.  It's non-destructive, so you can adjust it as much as you want without destroying the image.

Comment: Most likely a transparency issue with your 3D app's multipass layers when converting to 16bit. Best bet is to output to 16bit natively. Always good to increase your sample count too on lights and shadows. Also, if you don't need those multipass layer, exclude them.

Comment: In Cinema 4D, it would be like this: https://i.imgur.com/2AhUZaH.jpg

Comment: @InvariantChange thanks for ur suggestion will try that as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, from the comments I think I can see what you are trying to do. All those filters you are adding have basically destroyed the image.  Try to keep the edit simpler.

Here's my suggestion:

Convert the rendered image into a Smart Object, and use the Camera RAW filter to darken the image by reducing the exposure and highlights, to make it like a night scene.

Copy and paste the original render on a layer above the adjusted Smart Object, and mask out everything except the areas you want to stay bright - i.e. the lit up parts of the building.

Here's an example

[image]